# How to tell rebar to check for deps in another directory prior to downloading them?

Tags: erlang, dependencies, rebar

My Erlang project has two folders for applications, `lib` (with my own apps) and `deps` (with those defined in rebar.config to be fetched from git). One of the deps (let's call it A) has itself a dep (let's call it B). But I have my own, modified version of B residing in `lib`.

When I run get-deps, rebar downloads A (as it should), and then recursively looks for its deps, downloading B. Is there a way for rebar to know that I already have a version of B in `lib`, so it doesn't go and fetch it anew into `deps`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can fork A, and fix deps in rebar.config in the forked A that it points to your version of B.

And setup your project to use forked version of A